# Emulating GC with Doctrine

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

My idea is to to use the database (through ORM) as carefree as you deal with simple objects in a GC environment.

The basic idea is to use `cascade-remove` on most of the connections between tables, and just skip the failing steps. With a simple example:

```
Country (id, name)
1, UK
2, Germany

City (id, name, country)
1, London, 1
2, Brighton, 1
3, Schweinfurt, 2
```

This way when you remove City(3) then the removal will cascade to the Country(2) and it gets removed too (as it is not referenced any more).

If on the other hand you want to remove City(2) then the removal of Country(1) will fail - as it is still referenced by City(1) - and only the City entity itself would be removed.

The problem is that Doctrine will roll back the whole transaction so neither the Country nor the City is deleted. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Does Doctrine support SQL checkpoints?

Comment: @Orbling AFAIK It does not have such API.

Comment: As is usual with Doctrine, they dictate programming style - they are anti nested transactions, so advise against them and have half implemented them, rollback always busts the entire transaction. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/transactions.html#transaction-nesting

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? If not can you post the schema for both the city and country tables?